# translations using mediaelementjs

Tags: translation, mediaelement.js

How does the auto translations:['es','ar','yi','zh-cn'] work with mediaelement player

I tried the suggestion -

$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({

```
    // automatically create these translations on load
    translations:['es','ar','yi','zh-cn'],
    // allow the user to add additional translations
    translationSelector: true,
    // start with English automatically turned on
    startLanguage: 'en'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, Google has removed their translation API so this was pulled from MediaElement.js