# MediaElements Video component Auto-Translation of subtitles doesn't work

Tags: mediaelement.js

I don't see any subtitle other than English in their Example:

http://mediaelementjs.donteatthefruit.com/examples/?name=translation

Answer (score 1):

The google translation API is not free anymore, that's why it has been removed from mediaelementjs

[translations using mediaelementjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489683/translations-using-mediaelementjs)